# Scheduling Logic App to run Quarterly

Tags: scheduled-tasks, azure-logic-apps

I want to schedule a logic app to run on 10th day following the end of each quarter(10th January, 10th April, 10th July and 10th October).

I thought the configuring for recurrence trigger should be with following settings:

**Interval**: 4

**Frequency**: Month

**Time zone**: Easter Time

**Start time**: 2018-01-10T10:00:00Z

I tried with start time close to the current local time for testing but its not getting triggered. Need help.

Comment: Here is the documentation for complex schedules: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence
Note that you are specifying start time in UTC (the 'Z' format identifier), so probably that is why it is not getting triggered as expected.

Comment: Perfect. It worked. "Z" in the time format was the culprit.

Comment: glad to hear. posted the comment as answer.

Comment: Also note that an interval of 4 months cuts the year in thirds, not quarters

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you are specifying start time in UTC (the 'Z' format identifier); you want to specify it in local time instead.

```
{
   "startTime": "2018-01-10T10:00:00",
   "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
}
```

Full documentation for complex schedules is available here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence

Here is the documentation for complex schedules: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/…